# Smooth infinite animation flow with CSS

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to have a stack of images float infinitely across a block from top to bottom. To achieve that, I need the first (top) element from the stack to start floating right after the last element. What happens, in reality, is that the first element starts floating only after the last element reaches its destination, which causes a break in the flow. I tried playing with `animation-delay`, but it didn't help (or I didn't do the right thing).

[Here's the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/amhara/6xwrtjgv/21/)
Here's the code:

```
HTML:
<div class='one'>
</div>
<div class='two'>
 <div class='four'>
 </div>
 <div class='four'>
 </div>
 <div class='four'>
 </div>
 <div class='five'>
 </div>
 <div class='five'>
 </div>
 <div class='five'>
 </div>
</div>
<div class='three'>
</div>

CSS:
.one, .two, .three {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
}
.one, .three {
 background: yellow;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
}
.two {
 background: red;
}
.four, .five {
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 position: relative;
 animation-name: slide;
 animation-duration: 4s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.four {
 background: blue;
}
.five {
 background: purple;
}

 @keyframes slide {
     from { top: 300px;}
     to {top: -300px;}
}
```

Comment: This is verry hard to do with just `css`. Have you concidert using `javascript?`

Comment: I will turn to JS immediately when someone tells me it's **impossible** to do with CSS :-) so far it looks like I'm just missing something.

Answer (score 0):

With a little help from my friends, I solved it :-)

1) Floating blocks should have `position: absolute`;

2) Each floating block should have it's own `animation-delay` value, proportional to the length of the cycle and the number of blocks.

[Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/vqawxL7d/1/)